# C++11 iterate over jagged array?

Tags: c++, c++11, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to initialise a jagged array.
Why doesn't this work:

```
int *arr[10];
for (int *row : arr)
    row = new int[10];
```

it runs but then arr is unreadable.

How can I use this form of "for" properly in this situation?

Otherwise how can I just initialise a jagged array of X rows, each row is Y elements and set all to zero?

Comment: While it does not explain why it does not work, for Finagle's sake, just use `std::vector`.

Comment: That has way too many stars to be C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
int* arr[10];
for (int*& row : arr)
    row = new int[10];
```

Since you are changing the value in the array inside of the loop you need to iterate over references instead of values (which are only copies of what was in the array). This is very similar to function call semantics.

Comment: damn !, I was doing (int&* row: arr) instead ! should have thought of switching the order... thanks

Comment: No, you should've thought of not using raw pointers and C-style arrays.

Comment: `int &* row` IIRC is the illegal and nonsensical pointer to reference to int.

Comment: @Spacemonkey You could use `(auto& row : arr)` instead

Comment: @Spacemonkey C++ does not allow pointers to references (e.g., `int &*`).

Answer (score 1):

```
for(auto&row:arr)      // note the &. also note the auto
  row = new int[10];
```

the compilers should really warn about this stupid error. Happened to me many times.

Answer (score 0):

The provided answer by filmor is correct, but as others have already stated in the comments: If you really want to learn C++11 you should use a container like `std::vector`.

For example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> list;
```

And you're done. You can add as many `int`s as you like. If you want to have a fixed size list of dynamic int-lists, consider using `std::array`:

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, 10> arr;
```

Although I would always recommend using `std::vector` if performance or memory is not an issue. You have to make sure you're not exceeding the maximum number of elements anyway.

Concerning the `for`-loop, I would always try to use it this way:

```
for (auto &item : list)
```

If you don't want to modify the list, add `const`:

```
for (const auto &item : list)
```

Even if you don't want to modify the list, you're not making copies as you progress through it.

Comment: `auto const&`, because `const` is best placed on the right-hand side for consistency's sake (it can only be placed on the left-hand side for the outermost level which is awfully confusing)

Comment: if I don't care about performance, I wouldn't even use C++ at all.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think that's mostly a matter of taste and only leads to endless discussions as to what's right and what's wrong.

Comment: @Excelcius: in general, I don't care much about such issues (indentation, placement of braces, etc...); however in this case left-hand side placement can really be confusing. For example, consider a template method `void foo(const T&)`. If `T` is `int`, then you have a `const int&` which is a const-reference to an `int` and everything is well. If `T` is `int*`, then you have a `const int*&` which is a const-reference to an `int*`, that is the **pointer** is `const`, not `int`, even though `const` is closer to `int` and you read `const`, `int`, *pointer*...

Comment: @Excelcius: ... now write `T const&` and substitute `int*` for `T`. You then have `int* const&`, same type as `const int*&`, put it reads (from right to left) const-reference to pointer to int, which is exactly what it is. Of course, for an experienced developer it's just a quirk to be accounted for, but for a newcomer to the language, the inconsistency is utterly baffling.

Comment: @Spacemonkey There are 2 ways to think about performance. C++ in general performs better than most modern (often garbage-collected) languages. That's already the case if you use `vector`. You don't have to write potentially unsafe code to get this kind of performance. In very rare cases however, (high-end game development, scientific stuff, ...) you need to get that last bit of perf out of it. C++ allows this (pointer-arithmetic, asm-statements), but things can get really buggy really fast from there on. Most people do not need this extra performance at all.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't want to get into the details here in the comments, as there's already a ton of discussion on this topic on SO. I get your point, but: There is no such thing as a `const` reference. References are always `const`, they cannot be modified after they are initialized. Therefore `int* const&` should rather be written as `int *const &` which reads (from right to left): Reference to a constant pointer pointing to a non-constant `int`.

Comment: @Spacemonkey Don't think about "maximum performance".  You can always, always make code run faster.  Think about "performance per unit effort writing and maintaining code".  Maximize that, instead of performance, and you'll write programs faster *that are faster*, because instead of fiddling with manual `new` and fencepost issues in ways that have little to no impact on your runtime speed, you'll can then find the actual part that impacts runtime speed and spend your effort making *that part* faster.  The ability to drill down to a really low level does not mean you should do it everywhere.

Comment: @Spacemonkey Low level = faster is a fallacy. Even in the cases where you _do_ get better performance, the difference tends to be neglectable. Only swap out high level for low level operations to fix an actual bottle neck.

Comment: It's not just that low-level programming is generally faster, but C++ has a lot of optimised libraries and it seems to be the dominant language in areas where performance is important. The two main examples are CUDA and Intel libraries and compiler. My "main" programming language is C# and I would rather do everything in C#, but I want more performance, I want to learn stuff like CUDA and it's mainly in C++, and new stuff are released with a C/C++ API first then you have wrappers which are mostly incomplete/not up to date for other languages like .NET